# Why won't Thread.start start?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I can't seem to get this one working; Why won't `Thread.start` start?

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'socket'
print "choose host: "
host = gets.chomp
print "choose starting port: "
sport = gets.to_i
print "choose ending port: "
eport = gets.to_i
def scanner (sport, eport, host)
    while sport <= eport
        begin
            s = TCPSocket.new(host, sport)
            if s
                puts "Port #{sport} is open!"
            end
        rescue 
            puts "Port #{sport} is closed!"
        end 
        sport += 1

    end
end
Thread.start([scanner]sport, eport, host)
```

Comment: Not sure but maybe you need to Thread.join. ?  Maybe the main thread is exiting causes the whole process to terminate before the worker thread is finished.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling: this is exactly what happens here. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: Isn't it a bit redundant to start a thread and then immediately join it? That means the same work can be simply executed by the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join the worker thread from the main thread.  What is happening is the main thread exits which causes the entire process to exit, shutting down the worker thread before it has finished.

You need to wait for the worker thread by joining it after you start it.  Look for a function like `Thread.join` or similar in your languages threading api.

Comment: +1 ... which can be achieved by sending `join` to the return value of `Thread.start`, i.e. `thread = Thread.start(...); thread.join`.